# Iterate using each function JS

Tags: javascript, each

I have 3 `cards` in my `blade.php` which looks like this:

```
   <div class="container-fluid cfluid" id="cfluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 colmd1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
      id="roomT">A1</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed  "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
                id="roomT">A2</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
                id="roomT">A3</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

What I need to get is the text inside the span. Here's my code for the `each` function:

```
    $("#cfluid").each(function(){
        var title = $(".roomT").text();
        console.log(title);
    });
```

Howevrer I got this as a result which I know is wrong:

**A1A2A3**

In which it should be like this:

**A1**

**A2**

**A3**

Comment: IDs should be unique. You shouldn't be iterating over multiple elements matching `#cfluid`

Comment: the container-fluid `#cfluid` is only used once.

Comment: I did, and I still get the same result. As said, it is unique. It is placed on the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes (*card-body* and *roomT*) as part of the selector. Then simply use [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object to refer the current element to get the text:

```js
$("#cfluid .card-body .roomT").each(function(){
  var title = $(this).text();
  console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid cfluid" id="cfluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 colmd1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
      id="roomT">A1</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed  "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
                id="roomT">A2</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" 
                id="roomT">A3</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `#cfuild` as parent .You should loop the `.roomT`.And if you need a array result better use [`Jquery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead of `each`

```
 var res = $("#cfluid").find('.roomT').map(function(){
         return $(this).text();
    }).get();

console.log(res)
```

```js
var res = $("#cfluid").find('.roomT').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid cfluid" id="cfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 colmd1">
      <div class="card bg-success text-white">
        <div class="card-body">
          <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
          <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" id="roomT">A1</span>
          <small>time here </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="card bg-success text-white">
        <div class="card-body">
          <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed  "></i>
          <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" id="roomT">A2</span>
          <small>time here </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="card bg-success text-white">
        <div class="card-body">
          <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
          <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" id="roomT">A3</span>
          <small>time here </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly locate the `.roomT` element and loop as below

```js
$('#cfluid .roomT').each((index, element) => {
console.log($(element).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="cfluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 colmd1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" id="roomT">A1</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="cfluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 colmd1">
        <div class="card bg-success text-white">
            <div class="card-body">
                <i class="fa-2x fas fa-door-closed    "></i>
                <span style="font-size:30px" class="roomT" id="roomT">A2</span>
                <small>time here </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```